# Does Uber SDK for android have an OnRideRequested method or something like that?

Tags: java, android, uber-api

As the title says, i'm working with android uber sdk for an community anti crime app.

My app is using the Uber SDK to get rides as you'd do from Uber, so I want to implement a timer that sends the user location to his preference contacts every determined time. So my doubt is, there is any method like 'onRequestedRide' or something like that to work with?

I want the user's app to ask for the ride, and after they confirm and a driver confirm, start the timer to send the location.

**Update:**

UberTracking.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="request widget"
        android:textColor="@color/uber_white"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <com.uber.sdk.android.rides.RideRequestButton
        android:id="@+id/uber_button_white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        uber:ub__style="white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

UberTracking.java

```
public class UberTracking extends AppCompatActivity implements RideRequestButtonCallback {

private static final String DROPOFF_ADDR = "One Embarcadero Center, San Francisco";
private static final Double DROPOFF_LAT = 37.795079;
private static final Double DROPOFF_LONG = -122.397805;
private static final String DROPOFF_NICK = "Embarcadero";
private static final String ERROR_LOG_TAG = "UberSDK-SampleActivity";
private static final String PICKUP_ADDR = "1455 Market Street, San Francisco";
private static final Double PICKUP_LAT = 37.775304;
private static final Double PICKUP_LONG = -122.417522;
private static final String PICKUP_NICK = "Uber HQ";
private static final String UBERX_PRODUCT_ID = "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d";
private static final int WIDGET_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

private static final String CLIENT_ID = BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID;
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = BuildConfig.REDIRECT_URI;
private static final String SERVER_TOKEN = BuildConfig.SERVER_TOKEN;

private SessionConfiguration configuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uber_tracking);
    RideRequestButton uberButtonWhite = (RideRequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_white);


    configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setServerToken(SERVER_TOKEN)
            .build();

    validateConfiguration(configuration);
    ServerTokenSession session = new ServerTokenSession(configuration);

    RideParameters rideParametersForProduct = new RideParameters.Builder()
            .setProductId(UBERX_PRODUCT_ID)
            .setPickupLocation(PICKUP_LAT, PICKUP_LONG, PICKUP_NICK, PICKUP_ADDR)
            .setDropoffLocation(DROPOFF_LAT, DROPOFF_LONG, DROPOFF_NICK, DROPOFF_ADDR)
            .build();

    RideRequestButtonCallback rideRequestButtonCallback = new RideRequestButtonCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRideInformationLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(UberTracking.this, "DAMN GOD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ApiError apiError) {
            Toast.makeText(UberTracking.this, apiError.getClientErrors().get(0).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("SampleActivity", "Error obtaining Metadata", throwable);
            Toast.makeText(UberTracking.this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    };

    // This button demonstrates launching the RideRequestActivity (customized button behavior).
    // You can optionally setRideParameters for pre-filled pickup and dropoff locations.
    RideRequestActivityBehavior rideRequestActivityBehavior = new RideRequestActivityBehavior(this,
            WIDGET_REQUEST_CODE, configuration);
    uberButtonWhite.setRequestBehavior(rideRequestActivityBehavior);
    uberButtonWhite.setRideParameters(rideParametersForProduct);
    uberButtonWhite.setSession(session);
    uberButtonWhite.setCallback(rideRequestButtonCallback);
    uberButtonWhite.loadRideInformation();



}



@Override
public void onRideInformationLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Estimates have been refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onError(ApiError apiError) {
    Toast.makeText(this, apiError.getClientErrors().get(0).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    Log.e("SampleActivity", "Error obtaining Metadata", throwable);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

/**
 * Validates the local variables needed by the Uber SDK used in the sample project
 * @param configuration
 */
private void validateConfiguration(SessionConfiguration configuration) {
    String nullError = "%s must not be null";
    String sampleError = "Please update your %s in the gradle.properties of the project before " +
            "using the Uber SDK Sample app. For a more secure storage location, " +
            "please investigate storing in your user home gradle.properties ";

    checkNotNull(configuration, String.format(nullError, "SessionConfiguration"));
    checkNotNull(configuration.getClientId(), String.format(nullError, "Client ID"));
    checkNotNull(configuration.getRedirectUri(), String.format(nullError, "Redirect URI"));
    checkNotNull(configuration.getServerToken(), String.format(nullError, "Server Token"));
    checkState(!configuration.getClientId().equals("insert_your_client_id_here"),
            String.format(sampleError, "Client ID"));
    checkState(!configuration.getRedirectUri().equals("insert_your_redirect_uri_here"),
            String.format(sampleError, "Redirect URI"));
    checkState(!configuration.getRedirectUri().equals("insert_your_server_token_here"),
            String.format(sampleError, "Server Token"));
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == WIDGET_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
        if (data.getSerializableExtra(RideRequestActivity.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR) != null) {
            AuthenticationError error = (AuthenticationError) data.getSerializableExtra(RideRequestActivity
                    .AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            Toast.makeText(UberTracking.this, "Auth error " + error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(ERROR_LOG_TAG, "Error occurred during authentication: " + error.toString
                    ().toLowerCase());
        } else if (data.getSerializableExtra(RideRequestActivity.RIDE_REQUEST_ERROR) != null) {
            RideRequestViewError error = (RideRequestViewError) data.getSerializableExtra(RideRequestActivity
                    .RIDE_REQUEST_ERROR);
            Toast.makeText(UberTracking.this, "RideRequest error " + error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(ERROR_LOG_TAG, "Error occurred in the Ride Request Widget: " + error.toString().toLowerCase());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Session to your request button and have a callback function for your purposes. 
This is explained well, with an example [here](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk#ride-request-button-with-eta-and-price).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Prateek, thanks for your quick answer, I tried the implementation that you provide me with with a dummy toast and it throws the toast at the beginning of the app and not when the travel has begun, do you know if i'm doing something wrong? I update my initial post with my code.

Comment: I am not an expert on this SDK, but shouldn't this code be in the onClick() method of the RequestButton, instead of in the onCreate() method?

onCreate() is executed at the beginning of the app launch, which would explain the symptom you are seeing in your app.

Comment: Hi Prateek, if I add an onClickListener the app doesn't open the widget, it just shows the dummy toast, any other idea?

Comment: You are right about the position of the text. After a bit of searching, it seems that you have to deep link to the Uber app for this right now. There is an issue open similar to yours:https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/issues/57